# Escape null values LINQ

Tags: linq, sitecore

I have an issue with this linq expression:

```
var invs = ids.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => sitecoreContext.GetItem<Inv>(new ID(x).Guid))
                        .ToList();
```

How can I check for null into the .Select? SitecoreContext.GetItem(new ID(x).Guid)) to crash (because items being unpublished, or created but not published) so I need a way to verify first if the item exist, and only then to make the select.

Thank you.

Comment: so you're saying `sitecoreContext.GetItem<Inv>(new ID(x).Guid)` could return null and you want to exclude the nulls from the result?

Comment: Or is it the Guid that's null? (I'd guess not x.)

Comment: use a form of `.Where(y => y != null)`

Comment: Do you use any ORM like Glass Mapper or Fortis? Which version? What is the type of `sitecoreContext`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, I am using Glass Mapper, version 3.2.3.50, sitecoreContext is of type: SitecoreContext : SitecoreService, ISitecoreContext, ISitecoreService, IAbstractService, IDisposable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `SitecoreContext.GetItem<T>`, in the background `SitecoreContext` gets the item from the database and then it casts it to the T type. And from what I can see, it can throw an exception if there is no item with the specified ID.

What you can do to avoid this exception is split what `SitecoreContext` does and execute it on your own with a null check in between:

1. Execute `GetItem` first
2. Do the null check
3. Cast the item to your type:

```cs
var invs = ids.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => sitecoreContext.Database.GetItem(new ID(x)))
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(x => sitecoreContext.Cast<Inv>(x))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer. Thank you Marek ! Indeed, the sitecoreContext is changing for each publishing target and thus the null check is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter all non-null items using a `where` statement.

```
var nonNull = list.Where(element => element != null);
```

I usually use an extension method for this:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        where T: class
    {
        return enumerable.Where(element => element != null);
    }
}
```

Given your example, you could use the statement like this:

```
var invs = ids.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .WhereNotNull()
              .Select(x => sitecoreContext.GetItem<Inv>(new ID(x).Guid))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: I fixed the issue adding .Where(y => y != null) before adding .ToList(). I'll come back 
 with updates after testing.

Comment: @iusmar great, the `WhereNotNull` adds just some syntactic sugar but does essentially the same

Answer (score 0):

You Can Check Null Using null coalescing operator or  ternary Operator in Linq Example is Given Below

```
`var productTypes = from ProductDto e in Product
            select new 
                   {
                      Id = e.Product != null ? e.Product.ID : 0, 
                      Name = "xyz"
                   };`
```

Comment: OP is using the other Linq syntax though, and from context I'd guess they want to remove the null items from the list rather than generate zeros instead.

Comment: Yes i Agree With You. Depend on him

Comment: @Rup is right: i want to remove the potential null values within the collection.

Comment: @iusmar You mean where you have a non-null Guid but GetItem() returns null? Then you want the Mark's .Where clause from the question comments.